# How do I prevent Alert when App is on Foreground with Incoming OneSignal Push Notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification, onesignal

When my app is in the foreground, there is a alert that appears.  How do I prevent this from appearing when receiving push notifications?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of `AppDelegate` you have to add `kOSSettingsKeyInAppAlerts = NO`

```
[OneSignal initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions appId:ONESIGNAL_APPID handleNotificationReceived:nil handleNotificationAction:nil
                            settings:@{kOSSettingsKeyInAppAlerts:@NO}];
```

Comment: Note that `kOSSettingsKeyInAppAlerts` is now deprecated and `kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption` should be used instead.

Answer (score 6):

For Swift 3.0

```
// Initialize OngeSignal with Settings for Push Notifications
    OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: Constants.OneSignalAppID, handleNotificationReceived: nil, handleNotificationAction: {
        (result) in
        // Do Something with Notification Result
    }, settings: [kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption : OSNotificationDisplayType.none.rawValue])
```

Answer (score 3):

By default OneSignal shows notifications as alert dialogs when the app is infocus. To change this pass `kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption` with the value `OSNotificationDisplayTypeNotification` or `OSNotificationDisplayTypeNone` to settings on [initWithLaunchOptions](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--initwithlaunchoptions-).

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it this way. Add the following code in your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.none
```

on last line in

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.none
return true }
```

we have these 3 options

```
public enum OSNotificationDisplayType : UInt {


/*Notification is silent, or app is in focus but InAppAlertNotifications are disabled*/
case none


/*Default UIAlertView display*/
case inAppAlert


/*iOS native notification display*/
case notification
}
```

Here's [OneSignal Documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--initwithlaunchoptions-)