# How to prevent alert with incoming OneSignal notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I use OneSignal push notifications. When android app is in foreground and receives a notification, it creates an alert box with the notification. How to prevent this from appearing when receiving notifications?

Comment: Is the receiver implemented inside an activity? If it is that might be the problem. Try making the receiver a separate class.

Comment: Here is a similar question about ios [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165840/how-do-i-prevent-alert-when-app-is-on-foreground-with-incoming-onesignal-push-no?rq=1) So I think it could be solved by disabling some option, because it creates alert by default.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From The SDK [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v7.0/docs/sdk-reference#app-in-focus-notification-display) - When you startInit OneSignal, make sure to call inFocusDisplaying with "None" to disable OneSignal's in app AlertBox.

also on NotificationReceivedHandler section -

> Important behavior notes -
> If you will be displaying your own in app
> message when a notification is received make sure to call
> inFocusDisplaying with None to disable OneSignal's in app AlertBox.

Comment: As for the latest version of OneSignal SDK, seems that's deprecated right now.  Seems https://documentation.onesignal.com/v7.0/docs/sdk-reference#app-in-focus-notification-display is now the way to go

Answer (score 5):

Using this code line, I resolved my issue.

```
OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's changed in OneSignal 4.0.

For Kotlin:

```
OneSignal.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler { notificationReceivedEvent ->
    notificationReceivedEvent.complete(null)
}
```

For Java:

```
OneSignal.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler(new NotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler() {
  @Override
  void notificationWillShowInForeground(OSNotificationReceivedEvent notificationReceivedEvent) {    
     notificationReceivedEvent.complete(null);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues and I resolved it by using [inFocusDisplaying](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk#section--infocusdisplaying-)

here's how to use this in android.

```
    public class MyApplicationClass extends Application {

private static Context context;
PlayerIdsession session;

public static Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
    //MyNotificationOpenedHandler : This will be called when a notification is tapped on.
    //MyNotificationReceivedHandler : This will be called when a notification is received while your app is running.
    OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new MyNotiOpenedHandler())
            .setNotificationReceivedHandler( new MyNotiReceivedHandler() )
            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .init();

    OneSignal.idsAvailable(new OneSignal.IdsAvailableHandler() {
        @Override
        public void idsAvailable(String userId, String registrationId) {

            if (userId != null){
                session=new PlayerIdsession(context);
                session.savePlayerId(userId);
                Log.d("debug", "PlayerId:" + userId);
            }

           /* if (registrationId != null){
                Log.d("debug", "registrationId:" + registrationId);
        }*/

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line in your windows.plugin.signal

```
.inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
```

for example :-

```
window.plugins.OneSignal
.startInit("YOUR_APPID")
.inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
.endInit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to handle notifications while the app is in the foreground in the newest version 11, from https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/mobile-sdk#handling-notifications-before-theyre-presented-when-the-app-is-in-the-foreground :

```
let myLifecyleListener = function(event) {
  /// Display Notification, preventDefault to not display
  event.preventDefault();

  // Handle app in focus notifications here:
  console.log('foreground notification received:', event.notification)

  // Use notification.display() to display the notification after some async work
  // Uncomment this line if you would like the notification to be displayed
  // event.notification.display();
}
```

Then apply the handler: (This code applies to the Cordova version)

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.Notifications.addEventListener("foregroundWillDisplay", myLifecyleListener);
```